# Why is API Gateway trying to encode my binary data as a dictionary?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

For some reason, API Gateway is taking my binary data that I upload and is trying to parse it as a string/convert it to a dictionary.

I just want API Gateway to leave my binary data alone from my request. None of the other answers I have seen on SO have addressed the issue.

Is there a known solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default API Gateway messes with binary data. You have to set the binary content type for API gateway (which you can do through the [console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html)).

Be sure to double check that the `Content-Type` header in your requests is set to the correct value, and also the `Accept` header is set to the correct value.